# Polymer 1.0: Best practice for managing a simple list of items

Tags: javascript, list, polymer-1.0

I have created a simple prototype for displaying and editing a list of people. The prototype can be found here: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kunubecaxo/1/edit?html,js,output).

As you can see, when "Save" is pressed, the item is written back to the array using the [array mutation API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-mutation). I am not sure whether this is actually needed, since objects are always assigned by reference.

However, the "Save" button does *not* update the item in the list. *But* when you edit it again, the newly changed value is somehow preserved in the form. I guess the change does happen in-memory, but the `dom-repeat` does not trigger a new rendering of the list.

I have also set the `observe` property on the `dom-repeat`, but it does not seem to make any difference.

**My question is twofold**:

1. What needs to be changed so that the list will be updated upon saving the item.
2. Is there a better way (common best practice) for managing lists of items (with the usage of two-way data-binding).

Comment: Similar issue resolved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209556/polymer-binding-to-array-items-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Switch your save function to this

```
app.save = function(e) {
   app.splice('people', app.selectedIndex, 1, {name: app.selected.name, surname: app.selected.surname});
   app.selectedIndex = -1;
};
```

Long answer:

The reason you need to do this is slightly complicated, but it has to do with performance optimizations inside of dom-repeat. When dom-repeat's array gets updated, it doesn't simply delete all of its child nodes and re-render everything, because that could be expensive. Instead, it loops through all of the template instances it currently has as children, and checks to see if their item model has changed. For each template, it does a reference equality check to see if they are the same object or not. If they are they same, it does nothing. If they aren't, it re-renders that template.

In your case, you're splicing the array with the same object that is already there. So when the dom-repeat does this optimization check, it sees that the item is the same object as before, and does nothing. If you create a new object, however, this check will fail and it will re-render the template instance...thus, it works.

Now, why doesn't it just update when the object gets mutated? The answer to that has to due with the fact that Polymer's data checking is based on 'path notification', rather than something expensive like dirty checking. When a property gets updated, Polymer fires an event to every child node that is data-bound to that property. The problem is, your forms are not data-bound to the property as an element in the 'people' array. They're bound to a different property, 'selected'. And even though these are backed by the same object, the property names are different, so the notification paths do not match up; `app.selected.name` is the path that gets notified when you change John Doe's first name, not `app.people.0.name`, which is the path the dom-repeat is looking for change notifications along.

As for the second part of your question, I would recommend that you avoid two-way data-binding whenever possible. It doesn't rely on dirty-checking like Angular does, so it's not as huge of a performance problem, but it still does have a lot of overhead.

Comment: Since my splice is useless (the object is already there), would simply calling `notifyPath` do the trick? Or is creating a shallow copy of the object the only solution? What would be your solution for editing a simple list of items? How would you pass the object to the form and how would you copy it back? You said to avoid two-way data-binding, how can one achieve that? By making a shallow copy everytime?

Comment: I am sure notifyPath on the changed fields will also work. I have always used immutable objects and spliced in the new copy because in the apps I was working on we were making corresponding updates on the back end optimistically. If the back end update failed for some reason, we could roll back by resplicing the previous copy.

Comment: But what about the way I use `app.selected = e.model.item` for the purpose of editing the item. Is this OK or should I also make a shallow copy at this point? Could you please update my JSBin on how would you implement the whole process of editing an item in the array?